# trying to avoid an null reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need help avoiding the null reference exception in the code below, Where "equipmentSpaceAssociations" is enumerable empty and gives an error on the for-each loop below.

```
var spacesEquipmentAssociations = Spaces?.SelectMany(s => s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment.Where(e => e.AirHandlerId != null))
                ?? Enumerable.Empty<EquipmentSpaceAssociation>();
IncludeEquipmentAirflowsSum(exhaustEquipmentById, spacesEquipmentAssociations, true);
```

Below is the method

```
private void IncludeEquipmentAirflowsSum<T>(
        IDictionary<Guid, T> exhaustEquipmentById,
        IEnumerable<EquipmentSpaceAssociation> equipmentSpaceAssociations,
        bool isSubtraction = false)
        where T : class, IMinMaxAirflow
    {
        _ = equipmentSpaceAssociations ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equipmentSpaceAssociations));

        double sign = isSubtraction ? -1D : 1D;
        foreach (var equipmentSpaceAssociation in equipmentSpaceAssociations) // getting an error here
        {
            if (exhaustEquipmentById.TryGetValue(equipmentSpaceAssociation.EquipmentId, out var equipment))
            {
                    var multiplier = equipmentSpaceAssociation.Quantity * sign;
                    EquipmentExhaustAirflow.MaxAirflow += equipment.MaxAirflow * equipmentSpaceAssociation.Diversity * multiplier;
                    EquipmentExhaustAirflow.MinAirflow += equipment.MinAirflow * multiplier;
            }
        }          
    }
```

If I tried checking `equipmentSpaceAssociations != null` and `equipmentSpaceAssociations?.Any()`, I get the same error at this line `equipmentSpaceAssociations?.Any()`, and I am not sure where I am doing wrong.

Could you guys please help on the same? Many thanks in advance!!

Error details:

> System.ArgumentNullException   Message=Value cannot be null.
> (Parameter 'source')   Source=System.Linq   StackTrace:    at
> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument
> argument)    at System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)    at
> Domain.Shared.Models.ExhaustAirHandler.<>c__35`1.<ComputePropertiesMultiSpace>b__35_5(Space s) in C:\issue-dev\design-hub-dotnet\Domain\Shared\Models\AirHandlers\ExhaustAirHandler.cs:line 59    at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
> at
> Domain.Shared.Models.ExhaustAirHandler.IncludeEquipmentAirflowsSum[T](IDictionary`2 exhaustEquipmentById, IEnumerable`1 equipmentSpaceAssociations,
> Boolean isSubtraction) in
> C:\issue-dev\design-hub-dotnet\Domain\Shared\Models\AirHandlers\ExhaustAirHandler.cs:line 82    at
> Domain.Shared.Models.ExhaustAirHandler.ComputePropertiesMultiSpace[T](IDictionary`2
> exhaustEquipmentById) in
> C:\issue-dev\design-hub-dotnet\Domain\Shared\Models\AirHandlers\ExhaustAirHandler.cs:line 61

Equipment associations value
[image]

Comment: When you define you `spacesEquipmentAssociations`, note that the Linq query is _not_ evaluated at that time (it would be if you added a `.ToList()` at the end - you can do that for testing). Furthermore the `??` is useful only if `Spaces` is null. Then when you start enumerating, looks like that something is null in the chain `s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` for at least one element in the SelectMany. Are you sure your subproperties are properly populated? Or you can add some null guard here in the lambda, in case it works for you.

Comment: @topsail, I just updated the error info

Comment: Time to upgrade to .NET 7.0 and make use of [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references). Then you will likely get warnings for this.

Comment: I cannot upgrade to .net 7.0

Comment: The near-top reference to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where` implies to me that the error is outside of the code shown, and that the `IEnumerable<EquipmentSpaceAssociation>` being passed to the method is an expression tree that hasn't been evaluated yet.  Before passing the value to the method, if you try to materialize it with `.ToList()`, does the same error occur?  If so then it's time to trace back to the expressions being evaluated here because one of *those* would be what's failing.  **Edit:** Perhapes in `s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` there is an element that is `null`.

Comment: I just updated the image about the value of equipment associations

Comment: Looking at this further... I might expect this error if `s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` *itself* is `null` in the `SelectMany` operation.  Because `source` is generally the parameter of the object itself in an extension method.

Comment: @David,  any proper way to handle this if the above thing is correct

Comment: @kumar425: Well, if your debugging confirms that `s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` is indeed `null` then you'd handle it by checking if `s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` is `null` before calling a method on it.

Comment: @JonathanWood Nullable reference types depend more on the C# version than the framework version, and they've been around since C#8

Comment: @kumar425: Your screenshot shows that `equipmentSpaceAssociations ` is indeed null. I'm not sure why your null check fails. It may be because the assignment serves no purpose. Can you change it to `equipmentSpaceAssociations =?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equipmentSpaceAssociations));`?

Comment: Throwing different, more specific (like ArgumentNullException) is *the way* to avoid NRE - so not sure what else you need. Title of this post is quite misleading and lack of clear [mre] makes this post harder to understand and likely less useful for future visitors. Please review and [edit] the question  to align the title and body, ideally with clean sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a close look at the stack trace:

> System.ArgumentNullException Message=Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source') Source=System.Linq StackTrace: at

^ This tells us that the exception itself says that an argument to a method was `null`, and that argument had the parameter name `source`.  That's a common name for the object parameter in extension methods throughout LINQ, so this implies that a LINQ extension method is being called on something that is `null`.

> System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument) at

^ This is just the exception being thrown from a helper within LINQ.

> System.Linq.Enumerable.Where[TSource](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 predicate) at

^ This is the method that threw the exception.  Note the `source` parameter name.  So a call to `.Where()` is happening on something that is `null`.

> Domain.Shared.Models.ExhaustAirHandler.<>c__351.b__35_5(Space s) in C:\issue-dev\design-hub-dotnet\Domain\Shared\Models\AirHandlers\ExhaustAirHandler.cs:line 59

^ It's happening in the `ExhaustAirHandler` class, look specifically for `line 59`.  But between what we have above and the next line, we've found it...

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator2.MoveNext()

^ It's happening inside a `SelectMany`.

---

Putting all that together with the code shown, the problem is right here:

```
Spaces?.SelectMany(s => s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment.Where(e => e.AirHandlerId != null))
```

`Spaces` is not `null`, so the `SelectMany` is being invoked.  Within the `SelectMany` you are calling `.Where()` on:

```
s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment
```

For at least one record in the set, `s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` is `null`.

---

How to handle it is up to you.  You can remove elements with the relevant `null` properties from the collection before calling `SelectMany`, you can check for `null` within the `SelectMany` and return some default before trying to call `.Where()`, etc.

For example:

```
Spaces?
  .Where(s => s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment != null)
  .SelectMany(s => s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment.Where(e => e.AirHandlerId != null))
```

or:

```
Spaces?
  .SelectMany(s =>
    s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment?.Where(e => e.AirHandlerId != null)
  )
```

or:

```
Spaces?
  .SelectMany(s =>
    s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment == null ?
      new List<T>() : // where T is whatever type is used here
      s.AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment.Where(e => e.AirHandlerId != null)
  )
```

and so on.  It all depends on how your system *should* handle records where `AirBalance.EquipmentExhaustAirflow.Equipment` is `null`.  (It's entirely possible that there shouldn't *be* records like that and there's some other problem upstream from the code shown.)